# How to get username in models.py?

Tags: django

models.py

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    nowDate = datetime.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
    return '/'.join(['verify', UserVerifyImg.user_idx.username, nowDate, filename])

class UserVerifyImg(models.Model):
    user_idx = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        db_column='user_idx',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
  )
    business_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'account_user_verify'
```

I searched about `instance.user.username` but It is showed errer.

AttributeError: 'UserVerifyImg' object has no attribute 'user'

This is my error.

Comment: The `user_idx` field may still be empty when django tries to load the file. If you adds `print(instance.user_idx)` to the top of `upload_to`, what you see?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should use `UserVerifyImg.user_idx.username` in your views,
and in the `upload_to()` function, you should use `instance.user_idx.username`

Note: I have edited my code following your edit

Comment: I did like that.
but different error.

AttributeError: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'username'

Comment: Can you share the code which is popping this error?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this to get the username

```
instance.user_idx.username
```